# compile linux kernel module with mkfile

Tags: linux, module, compilation, kernel

can any one explain how this code compile and what is "all" and "clean"?

obj-m += ss.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

"`all`" and "`clean`" are understood be the `make` command. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

The "default kernel module Makefile" looks like this ...

```
obj-m    := ss.o

KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD    := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

... where you can see `default` used (instead of `all`) ...... and see what `clean` actually is doing.

---